# List_card in AoG passing item title to the next query instead of key

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

In an app, I'm returning messages of type `list_card` with option key for an intent.
Here is the json of a sample query:

```
{
  "id": "275212ef-cf97-4576-afa7-facfbc044ada",
  "timestamp": "2017-07-17T17:36:03.655Z",
  "lang": "en",
  "result": {
    "source": "agent",
    "resolvedQuery": "who is Sneha",
    "action": "cp.name_search",
    "actionIncomplete": false,
    "parameters": {
      "keyword": "Sneha"
    },
    "contexts": [
      {
        "name": "cpname_search-followup",
        "parameters": {
          "keyword.original": "Sneha",
          "keyword": "Sneha"
        },
        "lifespan": 2
      },
      {
        "name": "cpuid_search-followup",
        "parameters": {
          "keyword.original": "Sneha",
          "keyword": "Sneha"
        },
        "lifespan": 1
      }
    ],
    "metadata": {
      "intentId": "86bd1a17-8e9a-4956-b270-5fb4ac952f5f",
      "webhookUsed": "true",
      "webhookForSlotFillingUsed": "false",
      "webhookResponseTime": 135,
      "intentName": "cp.name_search"
    },
    "fulfillment": {
      "speech": "Searching...",
      "source": "agent",
      "messages": [
        {
          "type": "simple_response",
          "platform": "google",
          "textToSpeech": "Here are the search results.  \nWant anything else?"
        },
        {
          "type": "list_card",
          "platform": "google",
          "title": "Search results",
          "items": [
            {
              "optionInfo": {
                "key": "uid 72",
                "synonyms": []
              },
              "title": "Sneha Vasista",
              "description": "Srinivas Institute of Technology",
              "image": {
                "url": "//www.curlpad.com/assets/img/custom_images/user.png"
              }
            },
            {
              "optionInfo": {
                "key": "uid 2053",
                "synonyms": []
              },
              "title": "Sneha Bhat",
              "description": "Canara Engineering College",
              "image": {
                "url": "//www.curlpad.com/assets/img/custom_images/user.png"
              }
            },
            {
              "optionInfo": {
                "key": "uid 2114",
                "synonyms": []
              },
              "title": "Sneha Sajan",
              "description": "P.A College of Engineering",
              "image": {
                "url": "//www.curlpad.com/assets/img/custom_images/user.png"
              }
            },
            {
              "optionInfo": {
                "key": "uid 2320",
                "synonyms": []
              },
              "title": "Sneha ",
              "description": "sdit",
              "image": {
                "url": "//www.curlpad.com/assets/img/custom_images/user.png"
              }
            },
            {
              "optionInfo": {
                "key": "uid 2363",
                "synonyms": []
              },
              "title": "Sneha ",
              "description": "Srinivas School of Engineering, Mukka",
              "image": {
                "url": "//www.curlpad.com/assets/img/custom_images/user.png"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "0",
          "speech": "Here are the search results."
        }
      ]
    },
    "score": 1
  },
  "status": {
    "code": 200,
    "errorType": "success"
  },
  "sessionId": "e6aa9e52-a9e1-481a-adb5-476c5b386e02"
}
```

Now the problem is, when I tap the list item in AoG simulator, it passes `title` of item to next query.

[image: AoG simulation]

But while testing in **Api.ai simulator**, it behaves well and passes that `key` to the next query.

What can be the problem here?
Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using API.AI, then it will appear in the Intent as an `actions_intent_OPTION` Event.

[image]

One good solution is to have the Intent that sends the list with an OutputContext. Then create a particular Fallback Intent with `actions_intent_OPTION` as  Event and your desired `action` for that Context which should handle both the voice and press responses.

And you will find your `option_key` at `["originalRequest"]["data"]["inputs"][0]["arguments"][0]["textValue"]` instead of parameter.

You can also see the response value in the `actions_intent_option` context.

Comment: I tried this now. I added a fallback intent with action `actions_intent_OPTION`  with output content of list intent as input context. And that fallback intent is added with my required action which can handle inputs out of those options. Now tapping on options doesn't fail But backend in not receiving any parameter.

Comment: What is the backend receiving? can you post JSON?

Comment: Log of that json: https://pastebin.com/EyZK8B1D . btw nice hint, I can see that `option_key` in `originalResponse`

Comment: Reading and understanding the JSON always helps. {: I've also added another location to the answer.

Comment: Ya, Got it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is set up a fallback intent directly under your current intent.

For example, if you display the list from the default welcome intent, you can do the following.

1. Click "Add follow-up intent" and choose fallback.
   [image]
2. Don't forget to set the action and enable webhook in the fallback intent.

Now, you should be able to retrieve your answer from the fallback intent using the following code.

```html
const param = app.getContextArgument('actions_intent_option','OPTION').value;
```

Comment: I added fallback to that intent. But my backend is php and I responding to query intents by checking `["result"]["action"]` of request json. So how can I check it there? Also, I can see in training that now tapping on option invokes `actions_intent_OPTION` event.